# Altium - having trouble pouring copper

Tags: pcb, surface-mount, altium

[image: Altium Copper Pour]

As you can see above, I'm trying to make a copper pour connect all the GND nodes.

I could run a track and define its width to be huge (accomplishing the same thing) but I don't really think that's how it is supposed to work. I've tried all the settings (pour on all same nets, etc).

I have turned off ERC and all other layers too, so it shouldn't be a problem with those.

If anyone has some insight, it'd be great.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I had a plane design rule (Design >> Rules) giving me a 10 mil clearance on polygon pours. Removed it (for now), it fixed the problem. I'll have to exempt the polygons under these components for that rule. Thanks!